# C#-How to use empty List<string> as optional parameter

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Can somebody provide a example of this?

I have tried `null`,`string.Empty` and object initialization but they don't work since default value has to be constant at compile time

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Just use the null coalescing operator and an instance of empty `List<string>`

```
public void Process(string param1, List<string> param2 = null) 
{
    param2 = param2 ?? new List<string>();

    // or starting with C# 8
    param2 ??= new List<string>();
}
```

The problem with this is that if "param2" is null and you assign a new reference then it wouldn't be accessible in the calling context.

Comment: Yes,I get the limitation but this worked well for me in this case.

Answer (score 37):

You may also do the following using `default` which IS a compile-time-constant (`null` in the case of a `List<T>`):

```
void DoSomething(List<string> lst = default(List<string>)) 
{
    if (lst == default(List<string>)) lst = new List<string>();
}
```

You can simplify this even further to:

```
void DoSomething(List<string> lst = default)
```

Comment: IntelliSense is showing me the statement can be simplified even further by just using "default" instead of "default(List<string>").

Answer (score 6):

It is impossible. You should use method overloading instead.

```
public static void MyMethod(int x, List<string> y) { }
public static void MyMethod(int x)
{
    MyMethod(x, Enumerable<string>.Empty());
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to have a non-compile time constant, such as an empty list, as the default value. I know that you can use default values for parameters in C#, obviously...

Comment: However, this would be the only solution or anyone using a C# version before 4.0.

Answer (score 3):

```
    private void test(List<string> optional = null)
    {

    }
```

sorry about the string instead of list.
Null works fine for me on 4.0, i am using visual studio 2010

Comment: That's `string`, not `List<string>`

Comment: It compiles ,but you get Object Instantiation exception at run time

Comment: I did not get that exception, make sure you test your answers before making the claim.

Comment: Works fine for me, but needs to be at the end if you have multiple parameters

Answer (score 3):

As others mentioned you assign `null` to the optional parameter, in newer versions when using `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` you need to mark the parameter with the nullable annotation (?) and assign a null value to it, otherwise it will cause error `CS8625 - Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.`

```
void DoSomething(string param, List<string>? optional = null)
{
   // Check if the parameter is null, if so create empty list
   optional ??= new();

   ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I like it this way, it is more readable then `??=`

```
if (param == null) param = new();
```

Answer (score -3):

```
private void test(params object[] params)
{

}
```